# Is there any software to create logs of when someone installed/uninstalled programs?

Tags: installation, uninstall, logging

Is there any available application that would monitor all the logs of the installation and uninstallation of software. I want to know this because someone uninstalled one of my programs and I want to know what particular date it happened.

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no mandatory, universal software installation and removal system in Windows, there is no good way to do this type of thing.  You may try Windows Reliability Monitor, which may list that type of information, but that doesn't cover everything, I'm sure.

The fundamental problem is that if someone can uninstall software, they're an administrator.  If they're an administrator, they can erase their tracks pretty easily.  Consequently, unless you have something like a network level inventory system which logs this type of thing, you're going to have a hard time designing something which will offer any type of guarantee of accuracy.